# SQL Server multiple database nodejs connection

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to connect to SQL Server where I have few databases. I am using mysql library for nodejs. What I want to achieve is to connect to SQL Server and query different databases based on send query like this.

```sql
SELECT * FROM db1 where id = 1

SELECT * FROM db2 where id = 2
```

etc

My code:

```js
const express = require('express')
const mysql = require('mysql')
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express()

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '',
    user: '',
    password: '',
    database: '' // I want to pass db name in SQL query below not here
})
db.connect()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 //and here i want to pass db name in query not in above.
 //so every query that i send will contain db
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM users'

    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(result)
    })
})

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('Server started')
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just omit the `database` attribute in the `createConnection` object.
See [Establishing connections](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#establishing-connections)

```
...

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '',
    user: '',
    password: ''
})

db.connect()

...
```

Comment: thanks, can i console.log(db.connect())?? to check if is connected

Comment: console.log in general is a bad practise to check variables, just set a breakpoint and use the debugger ( https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/ ). But you can just inspect the db object there should be a property `connected`

Comment: If my answer helped and fix you problem i would appreciate if you set it as correct answer :)

Comment: This answer is related to MySql, whereas the question was specifically about MSSql

Comment: the question was tagged as mysql question and in the code example the mysql package was used